# How can I build two repackaged jars with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I'm trying to get spring-boot-maven-plugin to build two repackaged jars for two different main classes. I'added two execution blocks with their specific mainClass parameter in the configuration block but it seems that the plugin does not respect it because the configuration block is inside the execution block and not on plugin level and I always get

```
Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [com.mystuff.tools.b4commandline.Application, com.mystuff.tools.loadtester.Application]
```

here's the plugin section of maven-spring-boot-maven plugin of the pom.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>${artifactId}</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.mystuff.tools.loadtester.Application</mainClass>
                        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>b4-commandline</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.mystuff.tools.b4commandline.Application</mainClass>
                        <finalName>b4-commandline</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Any help on this would be great. I saw recipes on stackoverflow for the maven-plugin but those do not apply to spring-boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not make it work both within a single build (I'm not saying it is not possible though), however one option is to define **2 maven profiles**:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>one</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>one</name>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>com.xyz.LauncherOne</mainClass>
                                <finalName>one</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>two</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>two</name>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>com.xyz.LauncherTwo</mainClass>
                                <finalName>two</finalName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then, **build it twice** using both profiles (activated with a property in my code sample):

```
$ mvn -Done clean install
$ mvn -Dtwo clean install
```

It creates: `one.jar` and `two.jar`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `<classifier>`. Example:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>Pack application 1</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                      <finalName>application</finalName>
                      <mainClass>com.test.Application1</mainClass>
                      <outputDirectory>target/application1</outputDirectory>
                      <classifier>1</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                  <execution>
                    <id>Pack application 2</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                      <finalName>application</finalName>
                      <mainClass>com.test.Application2</mainClass>
                      <outputDirectory>target/application2</outputDirectory>
                      <classifier>2</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
```

Comment: This looks interesting but is lacking context. What's controlling the classifiers please?

Comment: this solved my problem. i didn't want to build with profiles as that would mean changing a shared microservice CI job for a monorepo. in my case i set the classifier of one execution to be ` <classifier>lock</classifier>` for the jar that, well locks, and ` <classifier>unlock</classifier>` for the sister tool that unlocks. then I get two jars .`./target/my-tool-2.14.7-RELEASE-lock.jar` and `./target/my-tool-2.14.7-RELEASE-unlock.jar`. so it seems your classifier is anything you want as a unique identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its doable, doing what you are asking would mean that the 2 jars produced would be identical except their manifest's `main-class` attribute. **I would rather suggest you to package a single jar and use spring profiles to launch it**:

```
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=profile1 YourApp.jar
$ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=profile2 YourApp.jar
```

This allows you to define 2 `application-${profile}.properties`, and @Conditional configuration classes, all based on the profile name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must consider first ***execution*** without ***id*** and another *execution*s with id; Then it is working.
for me below working fine:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!--<id>Batch 1(Don't put this one)</id>-->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>1</classifier>
                        <finalName>Core</finalName>
                        <mainClass>com.mainclass1</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Batch 2</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>2</classifier>
                        <finalName>BatchA</finalName>
                        <mainClass>com.mainclass2</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Batch 3</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>3</classifier>
                        <finalName>BatchB</finalName>
                        <mainClass>com.mainclass3</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```